# House with blind 'beastly' people living underneath it

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is an old horror movie (10-20 years) where a family (or maybe just a couple) move into an old wooden house and eventually find that there are 'people' secretly living there already. The house is in the middle of nowhere, so the protagonists are isolated from other people and can't reach out for help.

The 'people' living already in the house are siblings that are living in secret spaces between the walls and under the floorboards and eating rats to survive. They were trapped there as kids, and are now blind (lived in darkness for years) and don't talk (they forgot speech, just scream), and are generally crazy/dangerous. It is nothing supernatural, just abused and 'beastly' people.

The movie is in english language, and I once thought it might be some X-Files episode, although I've googled that and did not find results on it.

In short:

- Wooden house
- Strangers are visiting/moving there
- Obviously in the middle of nowhere, some field or something without help nearby
- Strangers get scared by noises and things moving
- Eventually we find that its not ghosts, but actual people
- These people lived inside the walls, under the floor, in secret passageways and leftover spaces
- They can't speak, just scream
- They're white and blind (from being in the dark all the time)
- They eat mice (maybe? there's some association with mice, I'm not sure what)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be from a Supernatural episode?

[Family Remains](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1222597/) (2009)

A bit newer then you described but the rest of your descriptions fits the episode well.

Some snippets from the IMDB synopsis:

> The Winchester brothers travel to the house, believing it to be a typical ghost case. They expect to find the house empty but meet the Carter family who has just moved to the country expecting to rebuild their lives after a tragedy.
>
> When the family is attacked by the same mysterious creature, the brothers protect the family with a circle of salt; however, she easily crosses this protection, and they realize that she is not a ghost or demon.
>
> But they notice that her eyes are clouded over -- she's never seen light.
>
> He wakes up and looks around...to see Girl in the Walls crawl in, smiling. She holds up a live rat and he recoils. She looks confused, then shows him what to do with it by taking a juicy chomp out of its neck.
>
> "He?" Dean asks? Yes, he. Girl in the Walls has a Bro in the Walls with her!

Answer (score 1):

[Bleeders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeders_(film)) (1997)

> John (Roy Dupuis) and Kathleen (Kristin Lehman) Strauss are a couple attempting to uncover the secret to John's rare blood disease. Along the way, they encounter Dr. Marlowe (Rutger Hauer), who is intrigued by the case. Little do they know that the island which they are about to set foot upon is home to the Van Dam family, mutant-like creatures who have become deformed and bloodthirsty from centuries of inbreeding. Their mutation began with their relative Eva Van Dam, who had an incestuous relationship with her twin brother. Also, they are fully functioning hermaphrodites, capable of reproducing with themselves. They need to survive on (dead or alive) human flesh.

Comment: Despite the sweet techno mix of Carmina Burana's *O Fortuna* in the trailer, that is not the movie

Answer (score -1):

The People Under the Stairs (1991). From IMDB:

> Two adults and a juvenile burglar break into a house occupied by a brother and sister and their stolen children and become trapped.

Title aside, the pale trapped people go in and out of the walls through out the house.

Comment: It's not that one. I distinctly remember people moving to the wooden house, like a classic horror movie where the family moves to a new house, and its haunted. Good try though